# Recovering the rows deleted from a large table

Tags: sql-server, recover

I unintentionally deleted some data in a large table. It's been a little while, only like 10 mins. I haven't closed the SQL Server yet. Is there a way to recover the data lost? Is there a way to see when and what kind of rows have been deleted? Please help.

I am not even sure whether it deleted data from that table. It has like 350 rows. It said "executing query" and I suddenly stopped the operation. Is there a way to see whether some rows have been deleted or not?

Comment: This [link](http://sqlbak.com/blog/recover-deleted-data-in-sql-server/) could help you

Comment: #1 Try `ROLLBACK TRAN` in the wild hope that you started a transaction before deletion. #2 Call your DBA and ask to restore last night's backup to another database #3 You might [need a tool like this](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-deleted-sql-data-from-transaction-logs/) to reassemble data from your transaction log.

Comment: Ouch. I hope you have backup recovery methods. There's not really a magical way to get it back unless you have. Differential backups can pin point the time you want to roll back to.

Comment: Is there a way to list the date and time the records were deleted ?

Comment: The happier news is that if you cancelled the delete statement prior to completion (the Red stop) that the deletion would have rolled back.

Comment: Yes, I cancelled it straight away...I wish :( so stressed out...don't know what to do

Comment: How did you delete the record? Right click on SMSS delete or via T-SQL DELETE?

Comment: using DELETE FROM TableName.  Other than that, there wasn't anything else.

Comment: I have already faced this problem but could not get the solution. I don't think, you get back records if deleted. But i think, there will be solution for it, but unfortunately we don't know it.